# Automate Visualforce PDF to corresponding G Drive Folder

Tags: google-drive-api, apex, visualforce, google-drive-shared-drive

- For every Load (shipment) my company does, the customer must be invoiced. To generate this invoice we have created a Visualforce Page that renders as a PDF.
- I have a shared Google Drive Folder named "Salesforce" that integrates directly with our Salesforce.
- Every time a new Load is created (load has it's own object) is created, I have created a flow that automatically creates a new folder for the corresponding load (i.e. if I create Load L-999, a folder will automatically create in the "GDrive/Salesforce/Loads" folder named "L-999")

What is the simplest way to create an Action button that will generate the Invoice PDF and save it to the corresponding G Drive "Load" folder?

I have tried creating a separate Apex Controller for the G Drive Folder and adding Apex Code to a different Apex class that's function is to Send the Invoice PDF to the customer via email.